# How to Install Adobes Suite from DVD without drive?

Tags: macos, adobe, installation

So I got the Adobe Creative Suite 6 (Design & Web Premium) for MAC but didn't have a optical drive on the MacBook.

What I have is a Windows PC with DVD and an older Macbook with DVD which are connected via LAN

I've tried to simple copy and paste the directory to install the software and also tried it with an image without success.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a SuperDrive for your Mac and do it that way. Alternatively, you can download an ISO of the CS CD (legal because you already own a copy) and mount it from OS X and install that way. I like the latter option because it's more technology and cos efficient, however, whatever floats your boat works.